# DATE_FORMAT displays NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp), 
    MAX(gallery.timestamp), 
    MAX(instrument.timestamp), 
    MAX(kurs.timestamp), 
    DATE_FORMAT('maxDate', '%d. %M %Y') as MaxDateFormat,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(gallery.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(instrument.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) 
            THEN MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp)
        WHEN MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(instrument.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) 
            THEN MAX(gallery.timestamp)
        WHEN MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(gallery.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) 
            THEN MAX(instrument.timestamp)
        ELSE MAX(kurs.timestamp)
    END AS maxDate
FROM ansprechpartner, gallery, instrument, kurs
```

The `.timestamp` columns have the type `timestamp`.

So the problem is, that I get a `NULL` value within my `MaxDateFormat`. Any idea what I might have missed here?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Zane I'm assuming Mysql based on the DATE_FORMAT function

Comment: @d3x do you realize you are not joining your tables on anything?  You are generating a Cartesian result.  Is that the intended behavior?  Not only that but you are using aggregate functions without any group by.

Comment: yes, I know. But do you think a JOIN would fix this?

Comment: @d3x There are so many issues with your query, no `GROUP BY`, referencing an alias in the same `SELECT`, no joins on your tables.  What exactly are you trying to do here?  Possibly, start from scratch and try writing this from the beginning.

Comment: Well, never mind the 40 other things wrong with your query, why do you have `'maxDate'` in quotes there? And is MySQL really able to reference an alias created at the same level?

Comment: @bluefeet makes since I didn't read that far as I find scrolling code unbearable.

Comment: Sorry I'm not that familiar with SQL. All I tried to do is compare each timestamp from all tables to get the highest timestamp out of all tables and format it in the way I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access alias name `maxDate` in same SELECT list in which it is defined.
Although you are not geting error because you have written maxDate in qoutes making it a string literal which expectedly fails to be converted into dateformat and returns NULL.
Use a derived table expression like below

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,DATE_FORMAT(maxDate, '%d. %M %Y') as MaxDateFormat,maxDate 
FROM

(   SELECT 
    MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) as col1, 
    MAX(gallery.timestamp) as col2, 
    MAX(instrument.timestamp) as col3, 
    MAX(kurs.timestamp) col4, 

    CASE
        WHEN MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(gallery.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(instrument.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) 
            THEN MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp)
        WHEN MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(instrument.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) 
            THEN MAX(gallery.timestamp)
        WHEN MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(gallery.timestamp) 
                AND MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) 
            THEN MAX(instrument.timestamp)
        ELSE MAX(kurs.timestamp)
    END AS maxDate
FROM ansprechpartner, gallery, instrument, kurs
) as z
```

In above query, the inner query is used as as a derived table on which further processing is done by outemost SELECT list.
Giving a name `as Z` to the inner query makes it sort of table which allows for SELECT clause to work on it.

Answer (score 2):

By quoting the column name `'maxDate'`, you a causing MySQL to treat it as a string literal, which can not be converted into a date, so the result is `NULL`.  Try it without quotes:

```
DATE_FORMAT(maxDate, '%d. %M %Y') as MaxDateFormat
```

Comment: This (the quotes) is an issue but your suggestion will not solve the other issues related.

Answer (score -2):

try this : -

```
select ansprechpartner_timestamp, gallery_timestamp, instrument_timestamp, kurs_timestamp, DATE_FORMAT(maxDate, '%d. %M %Y') as MaxDateFormat 
from 
(SELECT MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) as ansprechpartner_timestamp, MAX(gallery.timestamp) as gallery_timestamp, MAX(instrument.timestamp) as instrument_timestamp, MAX(kurs.timestamp) as kurs_timestamp,

CASE
WHEN MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(gallery.timestamp) AND MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(instrument.timestamp) AND MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) THEN MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp)
WHEN MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) AND MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(instrument.timestamp) AND MAX(gallery.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) THEN MAX(gallery.timestamp)
WHEN MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(ansprechpartner.timestamp) AND MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(gallery.timestamp) AND MAX(instrument.timestamp) > MAX(kurs.timestamp) THEN MAX(instrument.timestamp)
ELSE MAX(kurs.timestamp)
END AS maxDate

FROM ansprechpartner, gallery, instrument, kurs ) as table1
```

Comment: This helped a lot. The only thing I don't understand is the usage of your alias `table1`

Comment: @Zane It may produce correct result - but very inefficiently.

Comment: @d3x an alias should be given whenever we write a subquery, hence alias `table1`.